# TFS Renaming and deleting files is slow within Visual Studio 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

When, within Visual Studio 2013, I rename a file that is bound to TFS, Visual Studio pauses for around six seconds.  When I'm refactoring for example, this wait is really annoying because it interrupts my flow.

I suspect that when I rename a file it is contacting TFS and doing the rename on the server which is the reason for the pause and my wait (edit - I don't think this is the case because it takes exactly 6 seconds when I don't have internet connectivity).  If this is the reason, is there anyway to tell VS not to contact TFS until I check in?  If it is not the reason for the slowing down of VS while I rename does anyone have any solutions to quicken up this process?

**Edit - further information**
Visual Studio 2013 with update 2 and the free online version of TFS.  The pause occurs with or without internet access.  My machine is fairly fast (i5-2520M processor) with a SSD but it is 32 bit with 3gb of ram. I don't have many problems with memory though due to the SSD.
In terms of add-ins I haven't installed any other than the default (I only recently upgraded to VS 2013)

Comment: What version of TFS?  What version of VisualStudio?

Comment: TFS is contacted only for TFVC Server workspaces, but I never see a delay so long. If other operations, like adding a file, are fast, could be a client issue, like a conflicting Visual Studio add-in.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with update 2 and the free online version of TFS (I'm unsure if it has a version number but I just signed up a couple of weeks ago online).  Just to confirm the delay is just over 6 seconds for any rename of file or delete action but I just noticed adding a file is not affected.  This delay is increased if I'm refactoring because I am renaming multiple files.  I switched off my internet access and the delay is still 6 seconds.  My machine is fairly fast (i5-2520M processor) with a SSD but it is 32 bit with 3gb of ram.  Not had many problems with memory though

Comment: In terms of add-ins I haven't installed any other than the default (I only recently upgraded to VS 2013)

Comment: Have you looked at the Task Manager when the pause happens? Or at the Performance Counters of your machine?

Comment: Yes, one of the logical cores maxes out at 100% for the duration of the wait / pasuse

Comment: This problem is driving me insane. I have cleared various caches, changed registry settings and tried anything people have suggested so far online but with no luck. My VS, CPU usages goes to a constant 30%, no network traffic, very little hard drive usage. I had to delete a folder and it took half an hour. I don't know what the CPU usage spike is about and what it is doing. Adding files is also quick for me. Renaming or deleting is where the huge wait comes in. I have a self managed TFS and Visual Studio 2012

Comment: See my answer...probably not the answer you were looking for mind!

Comment: @Adam you found something since last year? problem just recently appeared for me (VS 2013 + TFS), no idea what triggered it (didn't installed new plugins etc).

Comment: @Guillaume86 - System reinstall for me unfortunately. Though just a thought try unbinding your project from source control and bind it again but in a different directory.

Comment: @Adam thx, I'll wait for VS2015 before trying that.

Comment: @Guillaume86 - 20th July for VS2015 and 29th July Windows 10. I'm planning a nice fresh install on the 29th on July :)

Comment: I'm using VS2015 and my solution is tiny (about 30 files) but deletes and renames take about a minute.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and the problem persist...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How big is your workspace?  VS 2013 supports local workspaces, which allow you to do more when you are offline.  However, if your workspace is large some operations can take a while when the files in it are scanned.  This blog entry gives a good overview:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/05/29/server-workspaces-vs-local-workspaces.aspx

Here is some relevant text from that blog:

"Local workspaces have scalability limitations due to their use of the local workspace scanner which checks for edited items. Local workspaces are recommended for most of our customers, because most workspaces fit into the “small” or “medium” category in our view – that is, they have fewer than 50,000 files and folders. If your workspace has more than 50,000 items, you may experience performance problems or TF400030 errors as operations exceed 45 seconds in duration. In this case, splitting your workspace up into multiple smaller workspaces (perhaps one workspace per branch), or switching to server workspaces is recommended."

With your SSD I am not sure this is the problem, but it seems worth mentioning.

To change your workspace from local to server, or just to see whether you do in fact have a local workspace, select your workspace on the Team Explorer window and choose Manage Workspaces. Highlight your workspace and select Edit, then select Advanced.  The type of workspace you have will be in the Location field.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had serious performance issues with TFS. The reason really were a number of folders with a large number of files.